# How many Persistent context can be possible in ejb

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, persistent

How many transaction & Persistent Context are possible in ejb ?

Answer (score 1):

As many as you want. There is no limit. If you look at the javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html), you'll notice the optional parameters that you can use. one of them is the **unit name**. this tells you which persistence-unit in the **persistence.xml** file you're pointing to.